# C'est de cela dont je veux parler

Tags: pronoms-relatifs

En recherchant des conseils qui pourraient m'aider à renoncer au sucre, je suis tombé sur le paragraphe suivant:

> Cependant, j’ai également découvert qu’il faut bien commencer quelque part. Et c’est de cela dont je veux vous parler aujourd’hui. Je veux vous parler de ce premier pas.

Bien que ma langue maternelle ne soit pas le français, je trouve tout de même que le "dont" ici n'est pas utilisé correctement. Ainsi, moi, j'aurais dis plutôt "Et c'est de cela que je veux vous parler aujourd’hui".

Me donneriez-vous raison?

http://arreterlesucre.com/quelle-methode-pour-arreter-le-sucre

Answer (score 6):

Oui, tu as raison de préférer *...de cela que...*.

Avec *...**de** cela **d**ont...*, il y a redondance étymologique du ***de***, donc pléonasme, mais cette forme étant présente dans la littérature, il est un peu exagéré de la considérer comme vraiment fautive, ce que fait cependant [l'Académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/cest-de-cela-dont-il-sagit).

Un pléonasme équivalent mais plus visible (redondance vraie du ***à***) est le suivant :

> C'est à toi à qui je répond.

au lieu de :

> C'est à toi que je répond.

ou

> C'est toi à qui je répond. (rare)

Le problème qu'introduit la phrase initiale est produit par la combinaison d'une phrase clivée et d'une proposition relative (Merci @GAMPUB pour son commentaire !).

Il est bien décrit dans le *[Guide de gram­mai­re française pour étudiants fin­no­pho­nes](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/relatives-clivees.html)* de Jean-Michel Kalmbach :

> Pour de nombreux francophones, cela pose un pro­blè­me. Comme la cons­truc­­tion c’est… qui in­tro­duit un sujet, il leur parait logique qu’un nom in­tro­duit par de soit repris par dont, ou qu’un nom in­tro­duit par à soit repris par où, etc. (voir ci-dessous). Exem­ples authentiques relevés sur divers types de sites Internet en français :

> *C’est de ce journal dont toute la France parle. [for­me correcte : C’est de ce journal que toute la France parle.] ... ■ *C’est ce jour-là où nous avons pris nos vacances. [for­me correcte : C’est ce jour-là que nous avons pris nos vacances]...

http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/relatives-clivees.html

Autre sources:

- [OQLF](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2904)
- [Blog Universite Paris Ouest](https://blogs.parisnanterre.fr/archives/rede/content/quand-le-csa-part-%C3%A0-la-chasse-aux-pl%C3%A9onasmes.html)
- [Parler français - Elklablog](http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/dont-a4569739)
- [Grevisse - Chroniques](https://www.grevisse.fr/le-blog-chroniques-grevisse/norme-et-usage/c-est-de-cela-dont-je-te-parle)

Comment: @Fólkvangr Je suis d'accord avec l'analyse de jlliagre, le lien qu'il donne montre bel et bien que l'Académie Française condamne cette tournure.

Comment: Dans un cas, on a une [clivée](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emphase_(linguistique)#Extraction_ou_phrase_cliv%C3%A9e) et dans l'autre une [relative](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposition_relative#Relative_avec_ant%C3%A9c%C3%A9dent). C'est le mélange des deux structures qui donne la phrase bizarre de la question...

Comment: @GAMPUB: Je n'ai pas compris ce que vous avez bien voulu dire, pouvez-vous m'expliquer ?

Comment: @SxEequals10nminus2n Regarde le lien que j'ai ajouté à ma réponse.

Comment: @GAMPUB: Les deux phrases ne sont pas connectées donc l'assertion est fausse.

Answer (score 0):

Mon hypothèse est que l'auteur amalgame deux sens apparentés (voir les sections *2<sup>e</sup> section I.B* et *2<sup>e</sup> section II.* du [TLFi](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/dont)).

> Cependant, j'ai également découvert qu'il faut bien commencer **quelque part**. Ce dont j'aimerais vous parler c'est de ce premier pas, par où commencer.

Answer (score -1):

« C’est de cela dont je veux vous parler aujourd’hui.» s'analyse comme étant constitué de deux propositions, l'une étant « C'est de cela » et l'autre « dont je veux vous parler aujourd'hui ». La première est la principale, qui doit pouvoir constituer une indépendante. C'est bien le cas puisque l'on peut dire « C'est bien de cela. », une phrase correcte. La syntaxe de ce qui reste dans la phrase initiale doit être conforme au exigences qu'imposent les mots qui y sont utilisés. Lorsque l'on discute une chose on ne dit pas que l'on « *parle cette chose* » mais on dit que l'on « *parle* **de** *cette chose* ».

Si on utilise « que », avec la forme « parler », on change son sens, il ne s'agit plus de « parler » en tant que  « discuter » mais de « parler » en tant que « s'exprimer au moyen de l'organe de la voix ».

- C'est ce langage que je veux vous parler aujourd'hui. (*que, pronom relatif*)
- C'est de cette fenêtre que je veux vous parler aujourd'hui. (Le pape, par exemple) (*que, conjonction de subordination*)

*Mais*

- C'est de cette fenêtre dont je veux vous parler aujourd'hui. (Le vitrier, par exemple)

Il faut garder à l'esprit que « de » dans « C'est de cela » ne fait pas partie de la relative.  Donc pour garder le sens de « parler » intact dans la relative  et en faire proprement le verbe « **parler de qqc** » on doit utiliser « dont », l'antécédent de ce pronom étant « cela ». Il n'y a donc pas d'erreur, pas de redondance. Il faut dire «  Et c’est de cela dont je veux vous parler aujourd’hui. ».

Le problème se trouve être que la personne qui a rédigé cette phrase ne s'est pas exprimée proprement. Ce qu'elle veut dire c'est qu'elle veut parler d'une certaine chose. Elle aurait donc dû dire « Et c'est cela dont je veux vous parler aujourd'hui. ».